# error in updating usehook object using spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How to target a key when I have multiple alike keys in an object. If I try to target my desired key, it shows a syntax error.

```
const [modifiedNonFormData, setModifiedNonFormData] = useState({
"author": {
    "lastName": "",
    "location": {
        "latitude": 49.3542671,
        "longitude": 8.133071
    },
    "shippingAddress": {
        "postalCode": "",
        "name": "",
        "address": "",
        "location": {
            "longitude": "",
            "latitude": ""
        },
        "email": "",
        "phone": "+14356234653"
    },
    "phone": "+14356234653",
    "firstName": e.target.value
},})


const phoneHandler = (e) => {
let val = e.target.value
setModifiedNonFormData(modifiedNonFormData => {
    return (
        ...modifiedNonFormData,
        ...modifiedNonFormData.author.phone:val
    )
})}
```

I am trying to update/modify onChange input value

Comment: Do you want to change the value of `modifiedNonFormData.author.phone`?

Comment: yes, this is what I am trying @Secret

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this instead:

```js
setModifiedNonFormData(data => {
    return ({
        ...data,
        author: {
           ...data.author,
           phone: val
        }
    })
})}
```

#### Explanation

You need to return a new object to a state setter in react. A common way to do this is through object destructuring. Let's say you have `data` and you want to clone it. You can do:

```js
const newData = { ...data }
```

This would copy all of the values from `data` to a new object. This is also the reason why modifying data works - you are copying the values but also setting a new value for a property:

```js
const newData = { ...data, newProperty: newValue }
```

However, this syntax is limited to replacing the value of a property. Therefore, if you want to modify the value of a property in an nested object, you have to also use the same syntax inside.